# Game character is not running towards target in a straight line with MoveTowards

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is a turn based game where the enemy character runs and hits the player's characters and then returns to its start position. The enemy's target object (one of the player's characters) is updated after each turn. In the first turn everything is correct and the character runs in a straight line towards the target. However in the following turns when the target changes it runs towards the previous target's position first before moving to the correct target and then it doesn't come back to start position straight away. Like I said, everything is correct in the first turn but when the target changes these behaviours occur.

```
public Vector3 startPos;
public Vector3 targetPos;

void Start() 
{
  startPos = transform.position;
  targetPos = playerCharacter1.transform.position;
}

void Update() 
{
Move(targetPos);
}

public void Move(Vector3 targetPos)
{
        StartCoroutine(MoveOverTime());
       
        IEnumerator MoveOverTime()
        {
           while (transform.position != targetPos)
      
            {
                    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPos, 0.04f * Time.deltaTime);
                    animator.Play("Run");
                    yield return null;
            }

                animator.Play("Attack");
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.2f);

            if (transform.localScale.x > 0f)
            {
                transform.localScale = new Vector3(-0.175f, 0.175f, 1f);
            }
            else
            {
                transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.175f, 0.175f, 1f);
            }
        
           while (transform.position != startPos)
            {
              
                transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, startPos, 0.04f * Time.deltaTime);
                animator.Play("Run");
                yield return null;
            }

            if (transform.localScale.x < 0f)
            {
                transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.175f, 0.175f, 1f);
            }
            else
            {
                transform.localScale = new Vector3(-0.175f, 0.175f, 1f);
            }
            yield return null;
        }
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming the `void Update` is a copy paste error, otherwise this wouldn't compile (`Update -> Update()`)?

Comment: yes, ofcourse. I will correct

Comment: Looks a bit odd how you're StartCoroutine every Update (IE, every frame). So around 60 times a second or so you're creating a new coroutine that is moving the transform to targetPos, attacking then moving back. I think essentially after a while you should have a LOT of different code running to different positions simuntaneously

Comment: Also, since your MoveOverTime() method is within the method, it should be closuring (essentially taking a snapshot of the values and using them throughout the execution) over the class variables (not sure how C# handles this), resulting in potentially unwanted behaviour such as targetPosition not changing if you called Move() before it was changed and it was changed during execution

Comment: This is the answer, thank you. I removed targetPos as a local variable and made it a public global that is updated and referenced from the coroutine.

Answer (score 0):

Moving targetPos to a public global value alone is not a good solution!

With the code you provided you are indeed creating a new CoRoutine with every Update loop (as pointed out by @Fredrik Schon). The reason that making targetPos global seems to "work" is that all of those coroutines are using that new location as the target. **However** you are still creating and executing many coroutines that will only be stopped when they finally reach transform.position == targetPos.

There are a number of things you should fix here:

1. Don't compare Vector3s (transform.position) like you are as they are floating point numbers. Use instead:

```
if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, targetPos) < 0.001f)
...
OR
if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, targetPos) < Vector3.kEpsilon)
```

See Unity example on this page: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html

2. Create only 1 coroutine and have it do the work for you. StartCoRoutine returns a *Coroutine* value that can be used to stop that specific CoRoutine. (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StopCoroutine.html)

```
Coroutine moveRoutine;
...
if (moveRoutine == null)
    moveRoutine = StartCoroutine(MoveOverTime());
```

At the end of your MoveOverTime coroutine, just set `moveRoutine = null;` and then you will ensure that if another Coroutine is needed one will be started. Or alternatively you could keep track of if you have a coroutine using a boolean that you set. Same principle.

3. Better yet, only start 1 Coroutine during your Start() and modify it to not quit. There is a small overhead in creating coroutines. If you know you plan to have 1 running the whole time your MonoBehaviour is alive, why not just start one at the beginning and add conditions to have it sleep (`yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);` when you don't want it do do anything. Or have it check if it must do any work at all and just `yield return null;` immediately if not.
4. Consider caching your WaitForSeconds. This is just an object like any other, so you can do the following:

```
WaitForSeconds attackPause;
void Start()
{
    attackPause = new WaitForSeconds(0.2f);
}
```

Then in your coroutine instead of `yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.2f);` use `yield return attackPause;`